# Open repo homepage with mvn

Tags: git, maven

In my pom.xml I have scm setup. Is there a mvn command that can open the repo page in browser for me?

Thanks

ps: pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    ...
    <scm>
        <url>scm:git:ssh://git@some.host:7999/projects/my-project.git</url>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@some.host:7999/projects/my-project.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@some.host:7999/projects/my-project.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>
</project>
```

Comment: I do not know if Maven provides this kind of feature, but if you're on Linux, this [script](https://github.com/yoannfleurydev/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/gitweb) can probably help you. I was inspired by some articles on the Internet. Just place this script in your PATH.

Comment: Thx, script will be more than enough !!

Comment: You're welcome :) @garyx